# NameError: uninitialized constant Statuspage::UserBuilder::NilClassUser Did you mean? NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is my code:

```js
module Statuspage
  class UserBuilder
    def initialize(user)
      @statuspage_user = "Statuspage::UserBuilder::#{user.class.name}User".constantize.new(user)
    end

    def build
      {
        subscriber:
        {
          email: statuspage_user.email,
          phone_country: statuspage_user.country_code,
          phone_number: statuspage_user.phone_number,
          skip_confirmation_notification: true
        }
      }
    end

    private

    MerchantEmployeeUser = Struct.new(:user) do
      def email
        user.email
      end

      def country_code
        user.country.code
      end

      def phone_number
        user.phone_number
      end
    end

    ConsumerRegistrationUser = Struct.new(:user) do
      def email
        user.email
      end

      def country_code
        user.country.code
      end

      def phone_number
        user.phone_number
      end
    end

    attr_reader :statuspage_user

  end
end
```

I receive this error on almost every test now:

Failure/Error:

```
@statuspage_user = "Statuspage::UserBuilder::#{user.class.name}User".constantize.new(user)
```

> NameError:
>     uninitialized constant Statuspage::UserBuilder::NilClassUser
>     Did you mean?  NilClass

otherwise, the code is running without any issues.

Comment: can you post the actual call? it seems like you are not propagating `user` argument in a correct fashion

Comment: You don't really need to explicitly pass the entire module nesting. `"#{user.class.name}User".constantize` will find a constant in the current nesting. I also don't really see the point of the structs which are identical, just use duck typing or generics.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're expecting to pass a `user` to `UserBuilder.new` which is a member of classes `MerchantEmployee` or `ConsumerRegistration` but instead you're passing `nil` into 'UserBulider.new`

so the problem isn't in `UserBuilder.new` per se, the problem is where you're calling `UserBuilder.new`.  Check in your tests where you build the `user` object... it may be it's not successfully built or found.